# php code to extract all text links not image link

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to extract all text link from a webpage using simplehtmldom class. But i don't want image links.

```
<?
foreach($html->find('a[href]') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>'; 
?>
```

above code shows all anchor links containing href attribute.

```
<a href="/contact">contact</a>
<a href="/about">about</a>
<a herf="/home"><img src="logo.png" /><a>
```

i want only /contact and /about not /home because it contains image instead of text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

foreach($html->find('a[href]') as $element)
{
    if (empty(trim($element->plaintext)))
        continue;

    echo $element->href . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
foreach($html->find('a[href]') as $element){
    if(!preg_match('%<img%', $element->href)){
        echo $element->href . '<br>';    
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it was typo. finally i have got solution by @katharas

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that in css and with phpquery as:

```
$html->find('a:not(:has(img))')
```

This is not a feature that will likely ever come to simple though.